# Alignment of DBEdits in a form doesn't work

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I Would like to align all the DBEdit Controls text to be displayed to the user left aligned

```
  for i := 0 to FormName.ComponentCount - 1 do
  if FormName.Components[i] is TDBEdit then
    TDBEdit(FormName.Components[i]).Field.Alignment := taLeftJustify;
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work.

When i define them individually it works.

```
DBEdit1.Field.Alignment := taLeftJustify;
```

Could some one tell me why it is like this?

Comment: It is called in Form.Create Method

Comment: Yes it is definded as var
  FormName: TFormName; How else i can achieve it ?

Comment: It is just guess-work currently because your question is lacking context and details. Your code to adjust the alignment for every `TDBEdit` can potentially work. Will it work when executed before components are created? No. Will it work when `FormName` variable points to something else then the form you want to alter? No. You see without the actual context it is impossible to give a definite answer.

Comment: Your code to adjust the alignment for every TDBEdit can potentially work - How to get it work then if not in Form.Create ?

Comment: I don't know, I had to guess, because I don't have enough information.

Comment: Have you debugged your code, to ensure your assignment is executed?

Comment: You've thrown us three lines of code, totally out of context, and given us a meaningless problem description (*it doesn't work*). It's like telling your auto mechanic *When I try to start my car, it doesn't work. But my friend's car does when I try it. What's wrong?* See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: @delsql Put your code in **OnShow** event of FormName

Comment: Is there any exception? Please drop here  statements

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in OnShow event of FormName :

```
procedure TFormName.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
for i := 0 to FormName.ComponentCount - 1 do
if FormName.Components[i] is TDBEdit then
TDBEdit(FormName.Components[i]).Field.Alignment := taLeftJustify; 
end;
```